# PHP mySQL Sort post by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a website where anyone can post anything to it without creating an account, long as its just text. My problem is because every time I start the website and post something. Its sent to the bottom, where oldest posts are at the top and new posts are sent to the top. I want to see the new posts on top instead. This is my first time working with PHP, mySQL and databases in general so my code might look bad. Tell me if more information / code is needed. Thank you for your time.

```
<?php
function setPosts($conn){
    if(isset($_POST['postSubmit'])){
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql= "INSERT INTO post(pid, date ,message) VALUES ('$pid', '$date', '$message');";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getPosts($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='post-box'>";
        echo $row['date']."<br>";
        echo nl2br($row['message'])."<br><br>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Type "mysql sort" into Google, and you got the answer ...

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. *Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ODRER BY` clause like below :-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Reference:- [ODRER BY clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

***Note:-*** Your insersion code is wide open for `SQL Injection`. Use `mysqli prepared statements` to prevent from it.

Reference:- [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Wow that makes me feel really stupid. But thank you for taking the time to read this and answer my question.

Comment: @SpaceOctopus or you can order the array in php, or, my preferred method, handle the display order with a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: @SpaceOctopus  glad to help you :):). Please take care of note section too

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `"ORDER BY"` to your `"SELECT"` to sort it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC";
```

The `"DESC"` is there so that new posts will be on top. We'd use `"ASC"` if we wanted older posts on top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort mysql result by date and order it in descending order.replace  mysql query to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post SORT BY date order BY DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPosts($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT date,message FROM post ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='post-box'>";
        echo $row['date']."<br>";
        echo nl2br($row['message'])."<br><br>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```